# Visual Studio 2015 Backword Compatability with SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

So I am taking a Database class with Visual Basic and the computers only have Visual Studio 2010 Professional with SQL Server 2008 express. Is there any way to make Visual Studio 2015 use SQL Server 2008 express instead of SQL Server 2014 to make databases so I can use them in class because I don't want to download visual studio 2010.

Comment: "make Visual Studio 2015 use SQL Server 2008 express instead of SQL Server 2014 to make databases" what?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Yes as long as you don't use methods that are only available in sql server 2014.